# Accessing a button by tag in navbar

Tags: iphone, properties, tags, uinavigationbar

I have custom buttons in the nav bar, I want to toggle their state by am  confounded by their accessors.

I know to get the button of a view (slightly different code than showed below) or cell I can do this:

`mybutton=(UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];`

How can I access the buttons of my navigation bar? (they are already set in code)

cheers
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the button and add it to the navbar instead of releasing the button retain it.  Then you can reference them whenever you need to.

So add a property to the view controller:

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *myButton;

Then in the method where you create the button use:

self.myButton = [UIButton ...

Remember to release the myButton in the view controller's dealloc method.

Comment: yes I could do that, it is likely what I will end up doing, but is there a way to access a button by tag after it has been released?

Comment: How did you add the custom buttons to the nav bar.  If it was using "UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonsView];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;" then you can refer to it using "self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem"